# SQL to Dataframe conversion

Tags: sql, dataframe, sas

I need help in how to convert this SAS code into Pyspark DataFrame? I tried to calculate the dates (+/- 2)

Pysaprk New dates calculations -

```
nuclear_df = nuclear_df.withColumn("two_before",F.lit(date_sub(nuclear_df.withColumn(FDOS_LN),2)))
                               .withColumn("two_after",F.lit(date_add(FDOS_LN,2))
```

SAS code that needs to be converted to pyspark DF :

```
select * from radio_df where MBR_ID not in 
      ( select distinct MBR_ID from radio_df a , nuclear_df b 
         where a.MBRID =b.MBR_ID and a.FDOS_LN between two_before and two_after )
```

Comment: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_add for syntax